# os.path.isfile alternative

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having problem with os.path.isfile, for example, this following code is part of my program:

```
for a in args:
    if not os.path.isfile(a):
        print _("Error: File not found: %(name)s  Ignoring...") % {'name': a}
    else:
        self.isup.queue(a)
```

and i have file called "box9.png" in my home folder, if i run:

```
% echo $PWD
/home/<username>
% /usr/bin/program-name box9.png
Error: File not found: box9.png  Ignoring...
```

but following work:

```
% echo $PWD
/home/<username>
% /usr/bin/program-name ~/box9.png
[program continue...]
```

can someone help me ?

I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: `print repr(a), os.getcwd(), os.path.abspath(a)` inside the loop

Comment: `% /usr/bin/pyis-uploader box9.png`
`'box9.png'/usr/lib/pyis-uploader /usr/lib/pyis-uploader/box9.png`
`Error: File not found: box9.png  Ignoring...`

Comment: you can [edit] your answer to include properly formatted output.

Comment: the output shows that current directory *is not* home directory i.e., somewhere in the script it is changed. Check for `os.chdir()` in the script

Comment: I wrote all script, and never used os.chdir()

Comment: hmm, on second thought, /usr/bin/pyis-uploader, is an shell script, that use "cd", i removed "cd" and it work, thanks, with your help i could see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of @J.F. Sebastian i solved my problem...

/usr/bin/pyis-uploader is an shell script, that contain:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/lib/pyis-uploader/
python2 pyis_uploader.py $@
```

I replaced with:

```
#!/bin/sh
python2 /usr/lib/pyis-uploader/pyis_uploader.py $@
```

And now work as expected!

Thanks, and Sorry my horrible English.